# htaccess rewrite subdomain to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to achieve getting subdomains pointed to subfolders so for example
`http://{subdomain}.example.com` points to `http://example.com/{subdomain}` without changing the URL in the address bar.

I currently have this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1 [L]
```

Which seems to work, but it changes my URL bar aswell

I knnow there are multiple questions about this, but none fitted my awnser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using virtualhosts instead, edit your httpd-vhosts.conf and add this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAlias *.yourdomain.com #wildcard catch all
  VirtualDocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/%1
  UseCanonicalName Off
  <Directory "opt/lampp/htdocs">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this lookahead based rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^.]+)\.[^:]+:(?!/\1/).*$
RewriteRule ^ %1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: This did not solve my problem, it behaves exactly as what I exlpained in my question. Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: This rule works pretty well on my web server. If it is changing URL then problem might be your browser cache.